# Parar una hebra

Tags: java, android, hilos

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public class ThreadRecibir implements Runnable {

    private String stringData=null;
    private  final int puerto=9002;
    public static boolean end=false;


    @Override
    public void run() {

        try{
            ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(puerto);
            int contador=0;
            while(!end){
                try{
                    ss.setSoTimeout(4000);
                    Socket s=ss.accept();

                    BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                    PrintWriter output=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
                    stringData=input.readLine();
                    output.flush();
                    contador++;

                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }catch (InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    output.close();
                    s.close();
                }catch (SocketTimeoutException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    end=true;
                }

            }
            ss.close();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }


}
```

y me gustaría saber cómo puedo interrumpir la hebra cuando salte la excepción de `SocketTimeoutException`. A dicha hebra la estoy llamando desde una `activity`.

Comment: Hablas de activity. Este código es android?

Comment: sí, es en android